How to import and use KMP library (ios-artifact) in pure ios project?
I want to use KMP library in my pure iOS project but cannot figure out how to do it.
The library is available in different artifacts including android, -iosarm64, -iosx64, -iossimulatorarm64, etc.
I don't understand how can I use that library in my pure iOS project. Can some one help me with this? Can I import and use KMP library of iOS artifact in my pure iOS project?
The library is published in Maven Central.

Please find this article for the same -
https://www.marcogomiero.com/workshops/introducing-kotlin-multiplatform-in-an-existing-mobile-app
